# Let $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous and $\Gamma (f) \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ be the graph of $f$. Show that $\Gamma (f)$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous and $\Gamma (f) \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ be the graph of $f$. Show that $\Gamma (f)$ is connected.

I’m trying to get a contradiction by supposing that $\Gamma (f)$ is disconnected. Then there exists $A$ and $B$ such that $\Gamma (f) = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. And showing that this violates continuity, but not sure how to proceed?

Comment: You probably mean "there exists $A$ and $B$ non-empty open (or closed) subsets of $\Gamma(f)$ such that..."

Comment: Did you consider trying to show it is path connected?

Comment: Do you know that images of connected sets under continuous maps are connected?

Comment: I haven’t covered path connectedness yet. Chapter on connectedness was before path connectedness on the book I read.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $\Gamma(f)=\{(x,f(x))|x\in\mathbb R)\}=(id_{\mathbb R}\times f)(\mathbb R)$.
The function $id_{\mathbb R}\times f$ is defined as
$$id_{\mathbb R}\times f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$$
$$x\mapsto(x,f(x)).$$